# Error Correcting and Decoding Delay

Tags: coding-theory

consider the $(3,1)$ repetition code $(000), (111)$; the $(5,2)$ code and the $(7,4)$ Hamming Code. (a) What is the error-correcting capability they all share? (b) What is the decoding delay of each code? (c) Which would you recommend?

I think the error-correcting capability has to do with the fact that they are both hamming code. I'm not sure how to determine it exactly or the decoding delay.

Comment: This is a question from your final exam, you should answer it on your own. What do you do with your students who cheat?